# All subdomains routed to same DocumentRoot, apache config

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

You've seen it done on sites like basecamphq.com where you would have username.basecamphq.com

I'm wanting to do a similar thing, any subdomain is routed through to the same index.php file.

so username1.example.com will request /home/some/path/to/www (in here is index.php) and username2.example.com will request the same file

I have it working locally, but my server uses cPanel. What would be your guess at the apache conifguration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot  /home/some/path/to/www 
    ServerName www.example.com
    ServerAlias *.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Something like that, perhaps?

Comment: worth noting that you'll also need wildcard DNS